# Life-cycle of php like we human have

Tags: php

hello i want to know about life cycle of  php 
just like human being  i guess each and every think has its life cycle
At first we were an infant  after that grow and becomer yonger then teenage , adult, oldage 
i just want to know that like we human have lifecycle every lanuage or think as its life cycle i just want to know about the life cycle of php

please provide how and what should be start and end of php 
i know its only written within `<?php ?>` but i just want to know each step of php programming 
please provide solution

Comment: What the heck? The life of PHP?

Comment: I don't think there is any "infant", "teenage" or even "adult" PHP. It's all PHP.

Comment: version 1, version 2, version 3, version 4, version 5, version 7

Comment: `<?php $programmingLanguage !== $livingBeing ?>`

Comment: i just want to know like in android their is life cycle onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
onPause()
onStop()
onRestart()
onDestroy()
is their in php or not

Comment: Language barrier, try to find a word other than "life cycle" because it's not translating too well. PHP doesn't have those sort of functions. PHP has already been created and started, can't be paused and if you stop it the website stops

Answer (score 0):

I have a graphical answer for your question.

PHP life cycle goes kind of like this:

[image: PHP life cycle]